# не могу подключить стили в Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal8

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка. CSS к тебе не подключается[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Моя невнимательность( всё сделал правильно, но в админке указал, что бы объединяло css файлы. Поэтому в коде не видел, что подключён мой файл

Comment: Так это был исчерпывающий ответ. Так как в вопросе и на скринах я всё сделал верно, и не видел подключенного css, только из за настроек в админке Drupal

Comment: Хм. Обычно просто в таких случаях я ожидаю, что автор внесёт правку вопрос и закрыть его как "не повторяется". Но в данном случае, вероятно. вы и правы. Извиняюсь.